# What does "apathy on matters African" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

"America’s apathy on matters African is one reason such initiatives have slowed of late." What does "apathy on matters African" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This contains an inversion sometimes used in formal speech or writing. The non-inverted version would be:

"America’s apathy on **African matters** is one reason such initiatives have slowed of late."

African matters = African affairs

It means that America doesn't care what happens in Africa.

Comment: I knew that inversion can be imposed on verbs, but 'matters' here seems to be a noun. Could the inversion also be fromed? If it is true, can I say 'people American' to refer to 'American people' i. formal context?

Comment: in formal context

Comment: No; it works in very few cases. *Matters* is one of them, possibly because that word itself is a little antiquated. It's an antique style, not really down to formality.

Comment: Got it. But where can I find a more complete list of words that can be used in such rare cases?